# StartCoroutine() to fix targetTexture.ReadPixels error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

As the title suggests I have a problem with the error occurring at the row

```
targetTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height), 0, 0);
```

Error:

> ReadPixels was called to read pixels from system frame buffer, while
>   not inside drawing frame. UnityEngine.Texture2D:ReadPixels(Rect,
>   Int32, Int32)

As I have understood from other posts one way to solve this issue is to make a Ienumerator method which yield return new WaitForSeconds or something, and call it like:  `StartCoroutine(methodname)` so that the frames gets to load in time so that there will be pixels to read-ish.

What I don't get is **where in the following code this method would make the most sense**. Which part does not get to load in time?

```
    PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
    Texture2D targetTexture = null;
    public string path = "";
    CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();

private void Awake()
{

    var cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
    targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

    // Create a PhotoCapture object
    PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, captureObject =>
    {
        photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
        cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
        cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
        cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
        cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;
    });
}

private void Update()
{
    // if not initialized yet don't take input
    if (photoCaptureObject == null) return;

    if (Input.GetKey("k") || Input.GetKey("k"))
    {
        Debug.Log("k was pressed");

        VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        // Activate the camera
        photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(cameraParameters, result =>
        {
            if (result.success)
            {
                // Take a picture
                photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't start photo mode!", this);
            }
        });
    }
}

private static string FileName(int width, int height)
{
    return $"screen_{width}x{height}_{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.png";
}

private void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
{
    // Copy the raw image data into the target texture
    photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);

    Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();

    targetTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height), 0, 0);
    targetTexture.Apply();

    byte[] bytes = targetTexture.EncodeToPNG();

    string filename = FileName(Convert.ToInt32(targetTexture.width), Convert.ToInt32(targetTexture.height));
    //save to folder under assets
    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Snapshots/" + filename, bytes);
    Debug.Log("The picture was uploaded");

    // Deactivate the camera
    photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
}

private void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
{
    // Shutdown the photo capture resource
    VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
    photoCaptureObject = null;


}
```

Sorry if this counts as a duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595055/readpixels-was-called-to-read-pixels-from-system-frame-buffer-while-not-inside) for example.

---

Edit

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822132/how-to-crop-captured-image-c?fbclid=IwAR11wFT5hUtoVeF48S1NQViCyoUGoaLGgF8MPC-DOEQVeOj9IYMZGKzg4DM) one might be useful when I get to that point.

Is it so that I don't need these three lines at all?

```
Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
targetTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height), 0, 0);
targetTexture.Apply();
```

As written in the comments the difference between using these three lines and not is that the photo saved has a black background + the AR-GUI. Without the second line of code above is a photo with the AR-GUI but with the background is a live stream of my computer webcam. And really I don't wanna see the computer webcam but what the HoloLens sees.

Comment: wait what are you going to do there? `targetTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height), 0, 0);` (tries to) makes a **Screenshot** .. therefore you have to wait until the end of the frame so everything is already rendered ... do you really want to make a screenshot and overwrite your texture right after taking a picture with the photocapture?

Comment: umm, @derHugo well that sounds kinda unnecessary, is that the row above the readPixels row setting the `cameraResolution`? (and honestly I would like to crop the captured photo from the center in the end and am thinking that maybe that is possible with this code row? Beginning the new rect at other pixels than 0, 0)

Comment: No, my point was the 3 code lines `Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();

    targetTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height), 0, 0);
    targetTexture.Apply();` make no sense to me ... you try to overwrite the just received texture from the photocapture with a screenshot ... (and cameraResolution also is the resolution of the device's camera not the screen resolution btw). What exactly do you need to crop the texture for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Crop Captured Image? --C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822132/how-to-crop-captured-image-c)

Comment: So I don't need any of these for my purpose really? O.o

When capturing a photo with this (redundant) code the photo saved has a black background and the AR-GUI I've added and without the code is the AR-GUI but with the background is a live stream of my computer webcam. And really I don't wanna see the computer webcam but what the HoloLens sees. (@derHugo sorry man for me being all over the place)

Comment: @derHugo for being anymore annoying I also have trouble taking more than one photo. The pressed key only registers once (if at all, have had some problems with that too...) and does not react at all when pushed a second time when the `OnStoppedPhotoMode` is done running.

Comment: @derhugo This is not a duplicate since the question involves an XR camera rather than a web camera so the solutions vary.  Plus, no cropping.

Comment: @ickydime it is the same since the duplicate isn't about how to crop an image specifically for a we come but a `Texture2D` in general... What do you think is the difference between a webcam and the XR devices camera?

Comment: @derhugo They are different APIs. Sure, they both are similar concepts in that you capture a byte array and apply that array to a texture.  But a webcam does not capture the mixed reality so it would be useless in this use case.  The author needs to use the XR code here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.WebCam.PhotoCaptureFrame.CopyRawImageDataIntoBuffer.html

Comment: @fearlessFox When you say are you seeing your live stream of your computer... are you running on your computer?  Have you tried running this on the Hololens?  The Hololens shouldn't have access to your computer's webcam.

Comment: @ickydime the code from [PhotoCapture](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.WebCam.PhotoCapture.html) is exactly the same for a webcam or the HoloLens camera .. Unity makes no difference. If you are using it with a webcam on a PC the Holograms simply will be the ones visiable in the Game the moment you take the picture. However as you can see OP used `PhotoCapture.Create(false, ...` so holograms will not be included anyway. and he should stay with `UploadImageDataToTexture` to directly get a `Texture2D` instead of calculate it.

Comment: @ickydime now thinking about it I don't really think we have to see the ar in the photo itself, only when using the app.

Comment: @derHugo Do you know if it is possible to use the hololens camera and not the webcam when trying out app in unity (before building). also asked: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/hololens/display-project-hololens-not-computer-webcam

Comment: @FearlessFox I don't know but I guess you can but it's probably really complex. The HoloLens has it's device portal which provides an access to the devices camera (but including holograms). Also I don't know if it allows you access it via sockets or maybe [Serial Port](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/serial-port-utility-pro-125863). However best would be you deploy and test on the device directly and on a PC use a webcam instead.

Comment: @derHugo Ah okay, I like it easy so I guess I'll try it with deploy :) Also really big thanks to you for all the help you provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your three lines

```
Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();

targetTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height), 0, 0);
targetTexture.Apply();
```

make not much sense to me. [Texture2D.ReadPixels](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html) is for creating a **Screenshot** so you would overwrite the texture you just received from `PhotoCapture` with a screenshot? (Also with incorrect dimensions since camera resolution very probably != screen resolution.)

That's also the reason for

> As written in the comments the difference between using these three lines and not is that the photo saved has a black background + the AR-GUI.

After doing

```
photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);
```

you already have the `Texture2D` received from the `PhotoCapture` in the `targetTexture`.

I think you probably confused it with [Texture2D.GetPixels](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) which is used to get the pixel data of a given `Texture2D`.

---

> I would like to crop the captured photo from the center in the end and am thinking that maybe that is possible with this code row? Beginning the new rect at other pixels than 0, 0)

What you actually want is cropping the received `Texture2D` from the center as you mentioned in the comments. You can do that using [GetPixels(int x, int y, int blockWidth, int blockHeight, int miplevel)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) which is used to cut out a certain area of a given `Texture2D`

```
public static Texture2D CropAroundCenter(Texture2D input, Vector2Int newSize)
{
    if(input.width < newSize.x || input.height < newSize.y)
    {
        Debug.LogError("You can't cut out an area of an image which is bigger than the image itself!", this);
        return null;
    }

    // get the pixel coordinate of the center of the input texture
    var center = new Vector2Int(input.width / 2, input.height / 2);

    // Get pixels around center
    // Get Pixels starts width 0,0 in the bottom left corner
    // so as the name says, center.x,center.y would get the pixel in the center
    // we want to start getting pixels from center - half of the newSize 
    //
    // than from starting there we want to read newSize pixels in both dimensions
    var pixels = input.GetPixels(center.x - newSize.x / 2, center.y - newSize.y / 2, newSize.x, newSize.y, 0);

    // Create a new texture with newSize
    var output = new Texture2D(newSize.x, newSize.y);

    output.SetPixels(pixels);
    output.Apply();

    return output;
}
```

for (hopefully) better understanding this is an illustration what that `GetPixels` overload with the given values does here:

[image]

and than use it in

```
private void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
{
    // Copy the raw image data into the target texture
    photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);

    // for example take only half of the textures width and height
    targetTexture = CropAroundCenter(targetTexture, new Vector2Int(targetTexture.width / 2, targetTexture.height / 2);

    byte[] bytes = targetTexture.EncodeToPNG();

    string filename = FileName(Convert.ToInt32(targetTexture.width), Convert.ToInt32(targetTexture.height));
    //save to folder under assets
    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Snapshots/" + filename, bytes);
    Debug.Log("The picture was uploaded");

    // Deactivate the camera
    photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
}
```

---

Or you could make it an [extension method](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/extension-methods) in an apart `static class` like

```
public static class Texture2DExtensions
{
    public static void CropAroundCenter(this Texture2D input, Vector2Int newSize)
    {
        if (input.width < newSize.x || input.height < newSize.y)
        {
            Debug.LogError("You can't cut out an area of an image which is bigger than the image itself!");
            return;
        }

        // get the pixel coordinate of the center of the input texture
        var center = new Vector2Int(input.width / 2, input.height / 2);

        // Get pixels around center
        // Get Pixels starts width 0,0 in the bottom left corner
        // so as the name says, center.x,center.y would get the pixel in the center
        // we want to start getting pixels from center - half of the newSize 
        //
        // than from starting there we want to read newSize pixels in both dimensions
        var pixels = input.GetPixels(center.x - newSize.x / 2, center.y - newSize.y / 2, newSize.x, newSize.y, 0);

        // Resize the texture (creating a new one didn't work)
        input.Resize(newSize.x, newSize.y);

        input.SetPixels(pixels);
        input.Apply(true);
    }
}
```

and use it instead like

```
targetTexture.CropAroundCenter(new Vector2Int(targetTexture.width / 2, targetTexture.height / 2));
```

---

**Note:**

> [UploadImageDataToTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.WebCam.PhotoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture.html): You may only use this method if you specified the **BGRA32** format in your CameraParameters.

Luckily you use that anyway ;)

> Keep in mind that this operation will happen on the main thread and therefore be slow.

However the only alternative would be [CopyRawImageDataIntoBuffer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.WebCam.PhotoCaptureFrame.CopyRawImageDataIntoBuffer.html) and generate the texture in another thread or external, so I'ld say it is ok to stay with `UploadImageDataToTexture` ;)

and

> The captured image will also appear **flipped** on the HoloLens. You can reorient the image by using a custom shader.

by flipped they actually mean that the `Y-Axis` of the texture is upside down.  `X-Axis` is correct.

For flipping the Texture vertically you can use a second extension method:

```
public static class Texture2DExtensions
{
    public static void CropAroundCenter(){....}

    public static void FlipVertically(this Texture2D texture)
    {
        var pixels = texture.GetPixels();
        var flippedPixels = new Color[pixels.Length];

        // These for loops are for running through each individual pixel and 
        // write them with inverted Y coordinates into the flippedPixels
        for (var x = 0; x < texture.width; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < texture.height; y++)
            {
                var pixelIndex = x + y * texture.width;
                var flippedIndex = x  + (texture.height - 1 - y) * texture.width;

                flippedPixels[flippedIndex] = pixels[pixelIndex];
            }
        }

        texture.SetPixels(flippedPixels);
        texture.Apply();
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
targetTexture.FlipVertically();
```

---

Result: (I used FlipVertically and cropp to the half of size every second for this example and a given Texture but it should work the same for a taken picture.)

[image]

*Image source: http://developer.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/sample-apps/targets/imagetargets_targets.pdf*

---

**Update**

To your button problem:

Don't use

```
if (Input.GetKey("k") || Input.GetKey("k"))
```

First of all you are checking the exact same condition twice. And than `GetKey` fires **every frame** while the key stays pressed. Instead rather use

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
```

which fires only a single time. I guess there was an issue with Vuforia and PhotoCapture since your original version fired so often and maybe you had some concurrent PhotoCapture processes...

Comment: Also this last part about the flip: I'm not gonna show the photo in hololens but send it further to an API (I got the code just haven't implemented it yet ^^),  does the photo taken also get affected by this flip?

Comment: Yes as far as I remember! For some reason afaik the Camera in the HoloLens is actually always flipped on Y. Sometimes while Vuforia was initializing I could even notice that all displayed holograms where also flipped vertically for a short moment. ^^ The reason I don't know but it might have to do something that Unity starts the Textrue Y coordinates at the bottom instead of the top. Simplest way would be just test it ;)

Comment: When debugging I try to see what `pixels` has for a value but visual studio and unity just buggs out leaving a `StackoverflowException` :S

Comment: And it does not seem to give `targetTexture` new value after calling `CropAroundCenter` but that is what is supposed to happen right? So that the image getting saved is the cropped one?

Comment: well the thing is there might be a lot of pixels (e.g. `1280×720 = 921600 pixels` and VS might have some trouble to load and display that array correctly). The second issue did you make sure you have `targetTexture.Apply();` after you cropped it? Otherwise yes it should be overwritten.

Comment: ok I don't know why but ... forget about the Extension Method version .. just use the normal `public static Texture2D CropAroundCenter ...` apparently I lied and you can't overwrite the input texture inside an extension method using `new Texture2D(...)`. I'll update my answer

Comment: and here I am once again .. I figured out how you still can do it as an extension method :)

Comment: hahah! I just got it to work with the other one hah! But really great answers Hugo! Today actually feels lika productive day thanks to you :)

Another problem though is why am I only able to activate `Input.GetKeydown("k")` once? It does not register the second time around.. (maybe I should make a new question)

Comment: You're welcome :) You should re check that `GetKeyDown` thing again ... in the code you posted you used `GetKey("k")` instead which fires every frame

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190848/discussion-between-fearlessfox-and-derhugo).